# About Shannon-McMillan-Breiman theorem for Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I am trying to understand the meaning of a version of the SMB equipartition theorem described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.08117) on Page $6$:

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a Markov chain, then $$\mu_n(\{x\})=\exp(H(\mu_n)+o(n))\tag{1}$$

for asymptotically $\mu_n$-almost all $x$ where $\mu_n$ is the distribution of $X_n$ and $H(\mu)$ is the entropy of distribution $\mu$.

> Does this version of the SMB theorem hold true for any Markov chain?

It is not clear to me if RHS of $(1)$ has dependence on $x$? Let's say $o(n)$ has dependence on $x$, then $(1)$ means that aymptotically $\mu_n$ is approximately uniform over it's support which is difficult for me to understand because an arbitrary Markov chain may have it's stationary distribution which is not uniform and here we are saying that $\mu_n$ is asymptotically uniform over it's support? Thanks.

Comment: If e.g. $o(n)\sim n^{0.5}$ you don't get uniformity in the sense you describe.

Comment: @Bananach I see, so $\mu_n$ could be far from uniform. Any idea why $(1)$ is called equipartition property then?

Comment: $H(\mu_n)$ behaves like $nH$ for a finite negative $H$. Therefore the right hand side in your (1) goes to zero, and in particular $\mu_n$ must spread over all integers (in the case of this paper) as $n\to\infty$

Comment: And o(n) is still better than O(n) in giving a bound on how far from uniform over the increasingly many integers this measure is spread

Comment: Btw, I'm far from am expert on this topic and I know equipartition as a statement about measures on the path space, not marginal measures, so I might be missing a point here

Comment: @Bananach True, I've seen a statement about measure on path space too.

Comment: Btw, one of the authors has written a blog post on this paper https://randompermutations.com/2020/03/19/mixing-time-of-a-pseudorandom-number-generator/

Comment: @Bananach Thank you very much, the post is insightful!